# Is it possible to call another application in our application activity?

Tags: android

I am trying to launch a third party application in my Activity(I want to launch that application in my Activity that should be in my application only)
I have no idea and have not I have not seen this type of question.

Comment: No, it is not possible to "run" the third party app inside your app.

Comment: i have doubt , when we are able to launch from our activity,why don't we  able to launch in our application?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You can only launch the other application installed on the phone.

For example :

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
if (launchIntent != null) { 
    startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible to open the another app into your app. But you can launch the app from your app using the package name of the another app.